# In Wordpress I want my sidebar to change based on the page

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, sidebar

Ok I just developed my first custom Wordpress theme using a guide - I'm still a noob. I'm not using widgets to fill the sidebar, I want to fill it myself with my own code and images.

So lets say I want the first sidebar I made to show up only on the homepage, and then the 2nd sidebar I made to show up on every other page. Can I use an if statement?

```
<?php

if(is_home()){

echo

"<div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
                <div id="search-box"><img id="search_text" src="http://localhost/Dorsa/wp-content/themes/Bootstrap/img/text_findyourhome.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
                <img class="box_shadow" src="http://localhost/Dorsa/wp-content/themes/Bootstrap/img/box-shadow.png" style="padding-left:0;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3"><div id="news" style="margin-top:275px;margin-bottom:200px">News</div></div>
         </div>"
         }

         else
         {
         echo
         "sidebar 2 code - didn't write it yet"
         }       
?>
```

Comment: I would suggest using templates and pages instead of if statements in your PHP. http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use if statement as said by @ChrisHerbert if you just want to display one sidebar in homepage and other in rest of your pages. New solution would be by creating a new template and sidebar.

1. First find your `sidebar.php` file and make a copy of it.
2. Name the sidebar using [wordpress naming convention](http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/) eg: `sidebar-secondary.php`.
3. Make changes in sidebar-secondary.php as per your need.
4. Make a new [template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) and use your sidebar as `<?php get_sidebar(‘secondary’); ?>`

**EDIT**

Assuming that you want one sidebar for homepage and separate for all others you can do the following.

1. Create `sidebar-secondary.php` as mentioned above.
2. The main template is usually `index.php`. This will usually contain the sidebar for your homepage. You will find some code like `<?php get_sidebar() ?>`.
3. If you want secondary sidebar on say page, open your page template `page.php`. Find the line `get_sidebar()` and replace it with `get_sidebar('secondary')`. Now all of your page will use secondary sidebar. You need to do the same if any of your page is using different template.
4. To display secondary sidebar in you single post page (the page displayed after user clicks readmore in blog section), open `single.php` and again find and replace `get_sidebar()` with `get_sidebar('secondary')`.

You can now style and use your sidebar differently for homepage and other pages.

Note that if you only want different sidebar in homepage and same for rest of the page you can also use conditional in your main template file `index.php`.

```
if( is_home() ){
 get_sidebar(); //your main sidebar for homepage
} else {
 get_sidebar('secondary'); //your sidebar for other pages
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Wouldn't I still need to use an if statement if I make a template? If I have the regular sidebar.php and a sidebar-secondary.php, wouldn't I have to call each one based on which page it's on in the index.php file? I understand the part where you're telling me to make two separate sidebar php files. I don't understand where to program them to appear on different pages. Please let me know.

Comment: Or would I leave it out of the index.php file and just call either sidebar.php or sidebar-secondary.php inside the content area of each page - is that what you're saying?

Answer (score 0):

Templates are definitely the way to go, but your solution should work assuming that your "home" page is your blog page.  If you've set the home page to be a static page (in the "Reading" section of the dashboard), you should use the `is_front_page()` function instead of `is_home()`.

I'd also suggest using alternative syntax and closing the PHP tag before your markup, like this:

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) : ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            <div id="search-box"><img id="search_text" src="http://localhost/Dorsa/wp-content/themes/Bootstrap/img/text_findyourhome.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            <img class="box_shadow" src="http://localhost/Dorsa/wp-content/themes/Bootstrap/img/box-shadow.png" style="padding-left:0;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3"><div id="news" style="margin-top:275px;margin-bottom:200px">News</div></div>
    </div>

<?php else: ?>

    <!-- sidebar 2 code - didn't write it yet" -->

<?php endif; ?>
```